# accessing Facebook Ad Library about Social Issues, Elections or Politics

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to replicate [this analysis](http://rpubs.com/zoowalk/FB_EP2019), using the [facebook ads library](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=political_and_issue_ads&country=DE&impression_search_field=has_impressions_lifetime) for political and social issues, but I am not able to collect the data using the access token I have from the app I have created. I am new to APIs, so I appreciate any help. What I did was the following:

1. Following the description [on this page](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/api/?source=archive-landing-page), I successfully confirmed my identity at Facebook.com/ID.
2. I have created an app using the Developer platform. App id: 704058403355716
3. After providing a privacy policy I have managed to change the status of the app to live.
4. I think I have created an access token with the format app_id|app_secret. The app_id is shown above.
5. I authorized the app to login in to facebook, so that I see the following green symbol: [image]

After doing all this, I thought it should work with R, using the code linked above. However, after asking the api for the info using:

```
#link to fb api
my_link<- "https://graph.facebook.com"

#define fields you are interested in
search_fields=c("ad_creation_time", "ad_delivery_start_time", "ad_delivery_stop_time",
                "ad_creative_body", 
                "page_id",
                "page_name",
                "currency",
                "spend",
                "demographic_distribution",
                "funding_entity",
                "impressions",
                "region_distribution") %>% 
  stringr::str_c(., collapse=", ")

#get the data from the first 'page' of data the api provides
page_one_response <- GET(my_link,
                         path = "/ads_archive",
                         query = list(access_token = my_token,
                                      limit=100,
                                      ad_active_status="ALL",
                                      search_terms="''",
                                      fields=search_fields,
                                      ad_reached_countries="AT"))
page_one_content<- content(page_one_response)
```

I get the following error:

```
$error
$error$message
[1] "Application does not have permission for this action"

$error$type
[1] "OAuthException"

$error$code
[1] 10

$error$error_subcode
[1] 2332002

$error$is_transient
[1] FALSE

$error$error_user_title
[1] "Authorization and login needed"

$error$error_user_msg
[1] "For access to the API you need to be authorized and logged into Facebook.To begin authorization, you can visit facebook.com/ID."

$error$fbtrace_id
[1] "AZl7qPjSYyLQzO4llVno5qk"
```

I thought it must be due to the access token, so I went back to the app and created a so called Sandbox Ad Account and asked for an access token (which never expires) using that. However, even when I use this new Sandbox Ad Account I get the same error in R.

I am not sure what should I do to proceed. I considered submitting the app for review (see the menu in the attached screenshot) but I think this is not necessary if I only want to use the facebook ads library for political and social issues, and I was also not sure what I should be asking the review for, given I am an individual researcher without a business verification. I was considering to ask for *Ads Management Standard Access* but I was not sure and in the end I did not.

Any suggestion how to make this work is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: As of recently you can use R ad Windsor.ai to access Facebook data. Maybe this will be helpful if you are still working on similar projects: https://github.com/windsor-ai/windsoraiR

Answer (score 0):

I think your API link is wrong. From their documentation (https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/api/?source=archive-landing-page) the full link is `https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/ads_archive`. In your code above you didn't put the API version.